# Concatenation of adjacent dates in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I would like to know how to make intersections or concatenations of adjacent date ranges in sql.

I have a list of customer start and end dates, for example (in dd/mm/yyyy format, where 31/12/9999 means the customer is still a current customer).

```
CustID | StartDate |  Enddate |
1      | 01/08/2011|19/06/2012|
1      | 20/06/2012|07/03/2012|
1      | 03/05/2012|31/12/9999|
2      | 09/03/2009|16/08/2009|
2      | 16/01/2010|10/10/2010|
2      | 11/10/2010|31/12/9999|
3      | 01/08/2010|19/08/2010|
3      | 20/08/2010|26/12/2011|
```

Although the dates in different rows don't overlap, I would consider some of the ranges as a contigous period of time, e.g when the start date comes one day after an end date (for a given customer). Hence I would like to return a query that returns just the intersection of the dates,

```
CustID | StartDate |  Enddate |
1      | 01/08/2011|07/03/2012|
1      | 03/05/2012|31/12/9999|
2      | 09/03/2009|16/08/2009|
2      | 16/01/2010|31/12/9999|
3      | 01/08/2010|26/12/2011|
```

I've looked at CTE tables, but I can't figure out how to return just one row for one contigous block of dates.

Comment: All of your CustID 1 records overlap, is the 9999 supposed to be some other year? As it is there's no consistent logic that would get your results as displayed.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote the wrong year in the third row. I've corrected it now so they don't overlap now. Year 9999 just means that I expect to have the customer until the end of time.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2005 (I'm pretty sure)

Answer (score 1):

This should work in 2005 forward:

```
;WITH cte2 AS (SELECT 0 AS Number
               UNION ALL
               SELECT Number + 1
               FROM cte2
               WHERE Number < 10000)
SELECT CustID, Min(GroupStart) StartDate, MAX(EndDate) EndDate
FROM (SELECT *
           , DATEADD(DAY,b.number,a.StartDate) GroupStart
           , DATEADD(DAY,1- DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CustID ORDER BY DATEADD(DAY,b.number,a.StartDate)),DATEADD(DAY,b.number,a.StartDate)) GroupDate
    FROM Table1 a
    JOIN  cte2 b
      ON b.number <= DATEDIFF(d, startdate, EndDate)
) X
GROUP BY CustID, GroupDate
ORDER BY CustID, StartDate
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7766f/1/0)

You can build a quick table of numbers 0-something large enough to cover the spread of dates in your ranges to replace the cte so it doesn't run each time, indexed properly it will run quickly.

Comment: +1 good one though I still have to read through to understand what you've done here :) see performance tests in my answer

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with [recursive common table expression](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
with cte as (
    select t.CustID, t.StartDate, t.EndDate, t2.StartDate as NextStartDate
    from Table1 as t
        left outer join Table1 as t2 on t2.CustID = t.CustID and t2.StartDate = case when t.EndDate < '99991231' then dateadd(dd, 1, t.EndDate) end
), cte2 as (
    select c.CustID, c.StartDate, c.EndDate, c.NextStartDate
    from cte as c
    where c.NextStartDate is null
    union all
    select c.CustID, c.StartDate, c2.EndDate, c2.NextStartDate
    from cte2 as c2
        inner join cte as c on c.CustID = c2.CustID and c.NextStartDate = c2.StartDate
)
select CustID, min(StartDate) as StartDate, EndDate
from cte2
group by CustID, EndDate
order by CustID, StartDate
option (maxrecursion 0);
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7766f/7)</kbd>**

Quick performance tests:

Results on **750** rows, **small periods** of 2 days length:

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e27fa/1)</kbd>**

- My query: **300** ms
- Goat CO query with CTE: **10804** ms
- Goat CO query with table of fixed numbers: **7** ms

Results on **5** rows, **large periods**:

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/66a3d/1)</kbd>**

- My query: **1** ms
- Goat CO query with CTE: **700** ms
- Goat CO query with table of fixed numbers: **36** ms

Comment: Looks like the second one was run with the cte not the fixed numbers table, cuts it down to 36ms from 700ms.  [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f0830/2/1)

Comment: @GoatCO sorry bro, my bad :( changed. I have in mind another approach but have absolutely no time to test it :(

Comment: That's always the case, so many things to do, so little time!